# What is the process called to change "fire" → "fiery"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, terminology

It's clearly not ["conjugation"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84868/fiery-what-other-words-spell-this-way), and I'm not even sure which keywords to use for google to help on this. Without having time to dedicate my next few days to read though linguistics textbooks, I thought the experts here might know.

Is it just "the adjective form"? There must be a name for the process that takes a noun and turns it into an adjective.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fiery -- what other words spell this way?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84868/fiery-what-other-words-spell-this-way)

Comment: @MετάEd, the two questions are superficially related, but this one is actually asking something quite different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a difference here between the sound and the spelling.

From the noun 'fire' to the adjective we get 'fiery'. From 'wire' we get 'wiry',  The pronunciation transformation is regular (the two rhyme).

There are other nouns ending in the sound '-ayr' (or in some varieties '-ah-yer' or '-ahr') which don't form an adjective this way, e.g. tire->tire-like.

Normally one doesn't refer to a suffix change for a noun to an adjective as a *conjugation*, or a *declension* (at least in English), or really even an *inflection*.  An adjective suffix is enough. *Converting*, *deriving*, or *transforming* will all work.

Comment: It's hard for me to authoritatively declare this the answer; I'm by no means an expert. However, you clearly have been selected by others as the answer by their voting. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

I think the general term you are looking for is "[derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28linguistics%29)".  The *[-y](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-y)* suffix is a "derivational affix" in morphological terms.  I'm not aware of a word for the specific process of turning a noun into an adjective.

The fact that the *-y* adjective formed from "fire" is irregular ("fiery", instead of "firey") is just an accident of the language.  There are many other nouns that produce irregular derivations (of all parts of speech): for instance *glory* + *-fy* → *glorify*.

Comment: adjectivization, actually.

Comment: @tchrist It isn't "gloryfy", so it's irregular.  There happen to be a whole bunch of words with the same irregular derivation rule, but that's no different than, say, stem-changing verbs in Spanish.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I thought of that on the way home but doubted it was used in practice.

Comment: @tchrist I can see that this is going to be like the time you tried to argue that the conditional future should never be used (you're still wrong about that, btw). In any given language there is *one* regular transformation rule for each class of transformations. ***All the other transformation rules are irregular.*** The way you tell which rule is the regular rule is you *make up a word* and you ask a native speaker to apply the transformation to it. In the case of the *-y* suffix, the regular rule is you just stick it on the end and you *don't change the stem at all*.

Comment: To head off the obvious nitpick, the word you make up has to follow the phonotactics of the language and it has to be designed not to trigger any special rules.  Sometimes this means you have to make up a whole bunch of words before you figure out which rule is *really* the default.  But this is all standard descriptive linguistics.

Comment: It doesn't *matter* that the irregular rules apply to a predictable class of words and make a predictable transformation!  They are not the rule that a native speaker would apply to an unfamiliar word with no special phonotactic properties, so they are not the regular rule.  Again: there is ONE regular rule per transformation.

Comment: I know *exactly* what I am talking about. Go read [The Child's Learning of English Morphology](http://childes.talkbank.org/topics/wugs/wugs.pdf). Belko. 1959. You are the one who does not understand (or, perhaps, to be charitable, you are hilariously out of date on how actual linguists analyze this stuff).

Comment: No, [that's the word that is used](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=adjectivization).

Comment: Also, Zack: Belko 1959 was a study of *oral* responses, not written ones, so I'm not sure what it has to do with i->y and doubling consonants. Perhaps you meant some other paper?

Comment: @MarkBeadles Belko was the first to demonstrate that there's *one* rule that is the default for any given transformation.  Later research generalized the principle to adults and written language.  Like anything in linguistics, it gets hairy in the languages with *really complicated* morphology ([Georgian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_language) is fun, read about it sometime) but the basic principle is just about as uncontroversial as anything gets in ling these days.  Well, West Coast ling.  I don't know what those people at MIT say.

Comment: Hmm, changing "y" to "i" before adding an ending is a pretty common phenonemon in English, like "study"->"studied", "company"->"companies", etc. It seems a little simplistic to say that only one rule can be the standard and everything that does not follow one simple rule must be considered irregular. There's little value in arguing over the definition of a word, but I would think it more useful to define "irregular" as meaning something that occurs very rarely. Like am/is/are is an irregular conjugation because we have no other pattern like it in the entire language.

Comment: @Jay The "one regular rule" principle winds up being more analytically useful in descriptive linguistics.  I was oversimplifying a little for effect, but only a little.  If you're curious, read up on "morphological productivity" (the references in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_%28linguistics%29 look plausible to me)

Answer (score 1):

I would call the variations [inflections](http://www.talktalk.co.uk/reference/encyclopaedia/hutchinson/m0006002.html) (or *inflected forms*)

> **inflection**: an ending *or other element* in a word that indicates its grammatical function in a sentence. (whether it is plural or singular, masculine or feminine, subject or object, and so on)

(Italics mine). I'm sure most people would agree the **-y** ending is an inflection (often  indicating adjectival usage). As Zack says, there's nothing unduly remarkable about the fact that *fiery* is "irregular" in other respects; I'd still call the *ire/ier* switch a form of inflection.

Comment: Actually no; this is derivational morphology, not inflectional morphology.  Examples of inflectional morphology at work include *cat/cats*, *mouse/mice*, *walk/walks*, *walk/walked*, *sing/singing/sang/sung*, and *big/bigger/biggest*.  Those are all inflections.  On the other hand, things like *care/careful/carefully*, *actor/actress*, and *dog/doggy* are considered derivational, not inflectional.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm aware of that distinction, but I think it's largely pointless. It seems to me that no useful purpose is served by dictionaries listing, for example, *helpless, helplessly, helplessness* as separate entries, while *radii* is normally only given as a plural form under *radius*. I don't see why "inflections" that change verb tense or number should be so fundamentally distinguished from those that change, say, an adjective to an adverb. But please don't spend a lot of time trying to tell me *why* I'm wrong - I just think what I think.

Answer (score -2):

Your guy's bickering over something so hard is actually very easy and basic. Here is what I Know is the right answer. 
The Old English word “fyr” (fire) was transcribed into Middle English as “fier.” (The Old English letter y, representing a long “i” sound, was written as “ie” in the Middle English version of the word.)

The Modern English spelling “fire” didn’t become firmly established until about 1600, but a trace of the old spelling survived in the adjective “fiery.”

Comment: No: in Old English, the letter *y* represented the /y/ sound and could occur in both a short and a long form, which were phonemically distinct. The same is true of the letter *i*, which in turn represented the /i/ sound and could also appear in phonemically distinct short and long variants. There is quite a large difference between /i/ and /y/, and no native English word we use today has /y/ in it: /y/ is rounded, as in French *t**u*** or German ***ü**ber*. OE spelling was phonetic.

Comment: Must be hard to never be wrong.